# Is possible upload an url file and chunking/partitioning it using fine-uploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to upload url files too, but in the examples I only can upload files from local machine. Is possible upload an url file and chunking/partitioning it using fine-uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader only uploads files on your machine, or on your network.  If you can't get to it with the file picker in your browser, you can't upload it.